# Set ABPerson custom ringtone

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, abperson

is there any way at all to modify a contact's ringtone in swift/objective-c iOS.
I've already searched for a possible solution without any luck. (PRIVATE APIs are not counted as solutions).
GRingtones is an app that is able to do what i want but no one seems to have any idea what APIs they used.

Comment: I'm surprised GRingtones is still on the store - the majority of reviewers say that it crashes upon group creation. Doesn't look like it's been able to get to the ringtones (and then only default ones) since October 2014? And, I also can't find anything in the public APIs.